# Where should I start if I want to create an operating system like windows

Tags: operating-system

I'm new here so excuse me if I am doing something wrong. The question is where and which programming language shall I study first in order to create an operating system like windows, linux, etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://wiki.osdev.org/Tutorials#Bare_Bones

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Before you start developing your own OS read also https://www.osnews.com/story/8162

Comment: To create an operating system like Windoze, drink heavily and do serious drugs. :-)